# How to use Validation Control Properly in Webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I am working on a project in which I have a web page named as Booking. I use validation controls as per requirement. They all work properly.

The Problem is that when user open a Booking page and want to move another page without filling any detail. All the validation controls show error message.

How can I stop that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `CauseValidation` property of the control you are using to navigate to the other page to *false*.

---

Refer to the following for more information about validation:

[Validating ASP.NET Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

on the control you use to move to the other page there a `CauseValidation` proprety that you could set to `false`.